# How to handle z-index on React components on a table

Tags: css, reactjs, z-index

I'm having some issues while displaying a modal on a table. For each expense data I render a expenseItem component inside of a tbody. When clicking on this components, it opens a lateral modal and a backdrop on the remaining screen.

Backdrop has a action that whenever is clicked, it closes modal. But, when I click inside of modal, it calls close modal action of backdrop on top of it.

I've tried to set z-index of backdrop to 100 and moda to 200. It didn't work.

```
return (
        <tr className="expense-box" onClick={() => handleOpenModal()}>
            <td className="expense-info">{description}</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td className="expense-info">{date}</td>
            <td className="expense-info">{debit || credit}</td>
            <td>
                <BackDrop isShowing={isModalOpen} closeModal={handleOpenModal} />
                <EditExpenseModal isShowing={isModalOpen} closeModal={handleOpenModal} expense={props.expense} />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Backdrop component:

```
function BackDrop({ isShowing, closeModal }) {
    return (
        <div onClick={closeModal}>
            {isShowing ? <div className="backDrop" /> : null}
            <style jsx>
                {`
                    .backDrop {
                        position: fixed;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                        z-index: 100;
                        top: 0;
                        left: 0;
                    }
                `}
            </style>
        </div>
    );
}

export default BackDrop;
```

Modal component:

```
import { useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import { editExpenses } from '../redux/actions/expenseActions';
import DropdownMenu from '../components/dropdownMenu';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

const EditExpenseModal = ({ expense, isShowing, closeModal, editExpenses, savedCategories }) => {
    const { id, description, date, credit, debit } = expense;
    const [ expenseItem, setExpenseItem ] = useState({
        date,
        description,
        category: '',
        subcategory: '',
        credit,
        debit
    });

    function handleInputChange(e, targetName) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        (value && !targetName) || (!value && !targetName)
            ? setExpenseItem({ ...expenseItem, [name]: value })
            : setExpenseItem({ ...expenseItem, [targetName]: e.currentTarget.innerText });
    }

    function onEditExpense(id, expense) {
        editExpenses(id, expense);
        closeModal();
    }

    return isShowing
        ? createPortal(
                <Fragment>
                    <div>
                        <div className="form">
                            <form>
                                <ul>
                                    <li className="form-inputs">
                                        <label>Date</label>
                                        <input
                                            className="field-input"
                                            type="text"
                                            name="date"
                                            defaultValue={date}
                                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                                        />
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="form-inputs">
                                        <label>Description</label>
                                        <input
                                            className="field-input"
                                            type="text"
                                            name="description"
                                            defaultValue={description}
                                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                                        />
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="form-inputs">
                                        <label>Category</label>
                                        <DropdownMenu
                                            savedCategories={savedCategories}
                                            handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
                                            type={'category'}
                                            category={expenseItem.category}
                                        />
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="form-inputs">
                                        <label>Subcategory</label>
                                        <DropdownMenu
                                            savedCategories={savedCategories}
                                            handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
                                            type={'subcategory'}
                                            parentCategory={expenseItem.category}
                                            category={expenseItem.subcategory}
                                        />
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="form-inputs">
                                        <label>Credit</label>
                                        <input
                                            className="field-input"
                                            type="text"
                                            name="credit"
                                            defaultValue={credit}
                                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                                        />
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="form-inputs">
                                        <label>Debit</label>
                                        <input
                                            className="field-input"
                                            type="text"
                                            name="debit"
                                            defaultValue={debit}
                                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                                        />
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </form>
                            <button onClick={() => onEditExpense(id, expenseItem)}>save</button>
                            <button onClick={() => closeModal()}>close</button>
                        </div>
                        <style jsx>{`
                            .form {
                                position: fixed;
                                background: white;
                                box-shadow: 0px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
                                display: flex;
                                flex-direction: column;
                                height: 100%;
                                top: 0;
                                right: 0;
                                width: 40%;
                                z-index: 200;
                                overflow: scroll;
                            }
                            .form-inputs {
                                display: flex;
                                flex-direction: column;
                                list-style-type: none;
                                padding: 1rem 2rem;
                            }
                            .form-inputs label {
                                margin-left: 8px;
                            }
                            .field-input {
                                margin: 5px;
                                width: 330px;
                                height: 40px;
                                font-size: 15px;
                                outline: none;
                            }
                        `}</style>
                    </div>
                </Fragment>,
                document.body
            )
        : null;
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    editExpenses: (id, expense) => dispatch(editExpenses(id, expense))
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => state;

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EditExpenseModal);
```

This problem started to happen when I've turned all structure to a table. Before I was using only `<div>` and it was working.

Comment: For z-index to work you need to set the position of element other than static. Since I don't know how your CSS looks if would be great if you can share an online example using codesandbox.io

Comment: How are you rendering the backdrop & modal, i mean what are the position atributes ?

Comment: @TArora23 i've updated with modal and backdrop components. But i`m using position fixed to both